# Javascript file not included only on home page

Tags: javascript, include

I have problem with loading my own javascript file, this problem is only on home page, on other pages it's ok.

Right now I've problem with interactivity, because only on homepage I can't do that.

Inside functions.php I've included my own script using this way:

```
    function monaco_assets_js(){

    wp_enqueue_script('script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '../js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'monaco_assets_js');
```

Comment: What do you mean by, on other pages it's ok?

Comment: only for home page not working, for other pages for example in navigation I have: Home, About, Gallery, Contact. It works fine for About, Gallery and Contact.

Comment: May I know the site URL?

Comment: it's on local host

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of two issues:

1. Unique handler is not used to enqueue scripts on homepage
2. Path to the file is wrong

**Unique Handler**

You should use unique script handler while enqueuing scripts or styles using `wp_enqueue_*`, I see that you used `script` as your script handler which is pretty generic and is not recommended. If you have used the same handler for one or more scripts, only the first script will be enqueued, the other ones will be ignored.

**Path to script**

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '../js/script.js'` this path goes to a parent directory of current theme and looks for `js` folder which I think seems to be wrong, do you have the script file there?

Comment: Hm I don't know what to say, I don't understand you. Look there is my functions.php: https://pastebin.com/vr0yFzs3

On other pages work fine, but only for homepage doesn't